# Testng test methods execution order not proper after specifying preserve order

Tags: methods, testng, execution

My testng file looks something like this:

```
<test name="Test1" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name= "workflowName"  value="wf_TEST1"/>
    <parameter name= "folderName"  value="SessionRecovery"/>
    <parameter name= "integrationServiceId"  value="isGrid1"/>
    <parameter name= "repositoryServiceId"  value="rs1"/>
    <parameter name= "waitForCompletion"  value="false"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.informatica.isp.qatests.functional.highavailability.test.TestSuiteConfiguration"/>
        <class name="com.informatica.isp.qatests.functional.highavailability.test.HATestCases">
            <methods>
                <include name="runWorkflow"/>
                <include name="sleep">
                    <parameter name= "sleepTime"  value="15"/>
                </include>
                <include name="killMasterNode"/>
                <include name="waitForFailoverAsPerRequirements"/>
                <include name="checkWfExecStatus">
                <parameter name= "sleepTimeBeforeCheck"  value="300"/>
                </include>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

But inspite of having preserver order set as True the methods are getting executed in Alphabetical order. Surprisingly this was working well when I was running them through eclipse. This has started creating problems when I am running them from Linux using mvn clean test. Any helps appreciated.

Thanks,
Abhisek

Comment: Is maven duly informed of your using testng.xml file, as per http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html ?

Comment: What is the version of the testng plugin and what is the version of testng in your Pom?

Answer (score 0):

I witnessed the same thing the other day.  For me, it boiled down to having test classes that didn't contain any runnable tests.  IOW, I had commented out all runnable tests in three or four test classes because they required extensive refactoring and I didn't have time to do the work right away.  For some reason TestNG completely freaks out and starts running tests (classes) in random order rather than in "preserved" order.  Once I added a little "@Test" stub method, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<test name="Automation" preserve-order="true"  enabled="true">
```

that would run your test methods in which manner you have written